# Regular expression : Match anything but full token

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following snippet where I would like to extract code between the `{foreach}` and `{/foreach}` using a regular expression:

```
{foreach (...)}
Some random HTML content <div class="">aklakdls</div> and some {$/r/template} markup inside.
{/foreach}
```

I already have:

```
{foreach [^}]*}
```

but I am unable to match anything after that. Is there any way to match anything BUT {/foreach} as a whole token? Please note that the content between {foreach}{/foreach} can also contain "{$" tokens.

**Edit**: BaileyP's & Tomalak's answers are correct, but I have chosen BaileyP's answer for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with this

```
/(?:{foreach .*?})(.*?)(?:{\/foreach})/gis
```

Tested with [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: Yeah. I'm feeling a bit stupid now. :-D Sometimes I think a bit too complicated, was typing up the same thing just now. +1

Comment: It's not foolproof, of course.  Nested foreach loops will break it - but that's a problem you can't solve with regular expressions alone anyway.

Comment: You can do nested foreach loops with Perl6 Grammars, and Perl 5.10 regexps.

Answer (score 2):

If your regex flavor did not support non-greedy matching, the following would do it, but since it does I recommend [@BaileyP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341531/regular-expression-match-anything-but-full-token#341603).

```
\{foreach [^}]*\}((?:.(?!\{/foreach\}))*[^{]?)
```

Depending on your regex favour, negative zero-width look-ahead and non-capturing groups look a little different.

Here are the components:

```
\{foreach [^}]*\}  // pretty much self-explanatory
(                  // match group one starts (that's what you are looking for)
 (?:               // non-capturing group starts
  .                // anything...
  (?!\{/foreach\}) // ... that is not followed by "{/foreach}"
 )*                // non-capturing group ends, repeat as often as possible
 [^{]?             // match the last character, unless it is "{"
)                  // match group one ends, done
```

Comment: Wow! You are Regex master! It works, but there is one problem, the last character just before the {/foreach} is not matched. How would you solve that?

Comment: You need to put the dot *after* the lookahead, not before it.